# Classify time series with unequal lenghts

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, moving-window, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a set of time series sensor measurements (acceleration and gyroscope readings) for driving events (harsh acceleration, harsh brake …) with the type, start and end of each event.
I need to classify those events in real time and the problem is that each event has different window’s size.
What are the lachine learning techniques that I can used ?

Comment: Do they have the same frequency (minute data, hourly data, etc...?)

Comment: Yes, 50 samples per second